# the image is displayed wrong

Tags: html, css

help, header banner is incomplete on phone screen

```css
.imgbanner{
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: -70px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0YP4.png');

}
```

```html
<div class="imgbanner">
</div>
```

[image]

How can I make it display well horizontally?

Real image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0YP4.png  **1024x312px**

Comment: Please add your code as minimal and runnable snippet. HTML and the CSS Selector is missing, as of right now we cant tell anything. And how is this related to bootstrap? I dont think it is, if it isnt, please remove the bootstrap-4 tag.

Comment: sorry, edited the post..

Comment: So you want the image to be fully visible all the time and scale to 100% width and its respective height when showing on smaller displays?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the width and margin. You also might not want to set a fixed height, because this will crop your image on smaller screens.
Like this, the text in the image might not be readable when viewed on smaller screens.

```css
.imgbanner {
    height: 200px;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* margin-top: -70px; */
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/fKnCN5Z.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbanner">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is on the phone screen, it is not complete horizontally

Comment: Maybe `object-fit` comes at use then.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove max-width and custom height property because this will crop your background image or try to add property `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

```
.imgbanner {
height: 200px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/fKnCN5Z.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;}

<div class="imgbanner"></div>
```